# Need to print the IP as list in bash script while resolving DNS

Tags: bash, ip, json

I'm writing the below bash script for terraform external data provider

```bash
# !/bin/bash
echo {\"ip\":\"`nslookup nlb-private-1-6ec90b26d1c9e906.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com | awk '/^Address: /  { print $0 }'`\"}
```

I got the output as

```
ssh_ip_address = "10.20.207.250 10.20.223.249 10.20.191.249"
```

I want to break this output as list with commas since I want to call each IP as different output for calling as inputs in terraform script.

Great if anyone can help

Comment: Does "list" mean a JSON list (`["10.20.207.250", "10.20.223.249", "10.20.191.249"]`), or do you simply want the values separated by commas (`"10.20.207.250,10.20.223.249,10.20.191.249"`)?

Comment: I get `{"ip":"Address: 10.20.207.250 Address: 10.20.223.249 Address: 10.20.191.249"}` using your code. Are you sure it gives the output you tell us it does?

Comment: @Kusalananda, i want as a JSON list. thank for asking

Comment: @Reshmi You might want to clarify precisely what you want as output in your question.  As you can see, you have a few alternative interpretations in the answers now.

Comment: Thank you all for all the answers out here. Appreciate everyone's time. I got the solution.

Comment: @Reshmi I've just seen you've mentioned in a comment that you wanted JSON output. This should have been **in your question** so that it's easy for people to see and act on.

Comment: @Reshmi also, if you have an answer please remember to accept it with the ✔

Comment: @Roima noted. Will make sure to follow those.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answeer @Reshmi, can I ask why did you select it instead of one of the others? It is certainly not the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this solution:

```bash
$ ips=$(nslookup nlb-private-1-6ec90b26d1c9e906.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com | sed -n '/Address: /s/[^0-9.]*//p')
$ printf '{ "ip": "%s\n' "${ips//$'\n'/,}\" }"
{ "ip": "10.20.207.250,10.20.191.249,10.20.223.249" }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want JSON as output, with the IP addresses as the value for a top-level `ip` key.

Depending on what you want in the end, you could use either

```bash
nslookup nlb-private-1-6ec90b26d1c9e906.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com |
sed -n 's/^Address: //p' |
jq -Rs '{ ip: ( rtrimstr("\n") | split("\n") ) }'
```

... which strips out the IP addresses using `sed` and then reads these into a JSON list with `jq`.  This will give you

```json
{
  "ip": [
    "10.20.223.249",
    "10.20.191.249",
    "10.20.207.250"
  ]
}
```

Or joining those IP addresses with commas,

```bash
nslookup nlb-private-1-6ec90b26d1c9e906.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com |
sed -n 's/^Address: //p' |
jq -Rs '{ ip: ( rtrimstr("\n") | split("\n") | join(",") ) }'
```

... which will give you

```json
{
  "ip": "10.20.207.250,10.20.223.249,10.20.191.249"
}
```

You may replace `nslookup` and `sed` with any command or pipeline that produces a set of lines of IP addresses.  For example, you may want to use the single command that roaima shows in [their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704368/116858):

```bash
dig +short nlb-private-1-6ec90b26d1c9e906.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

---

With the help of `dig` and `jo`:

```bash
$ dig +short nlb-private-1-6ec90b26d1c9e906.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com | jo -a | jo ip=:-
{"ip":["10.20.223.249","10.20.207.250","10.20.191.249"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't get anything like your output when I run your code, so I've started afresh. Here's a solution using `dig` instead of `nslookup` (and split over two lines for a little extra readability)

```
printf "ssh_ip_address = \"%s\"\n" \
    "$(dig +short nlb-private-1-6ec90b26d1c9e906.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com | xargs | tr ' ' ',')"
```

Output

```
ssh_ip_address = "10.20.223.249,10.20.207.250,10.20.191.249"
```

---

Having just found that you wanted JSON all along, here's a modified version of the same command that does exactly this

```
printf "{ \"ip\": \"%s\" }\n" \
    "$(dig +short nlb-private-1-6ec90b26d1c9e906.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com | xargs | tr ' ' ',')"
```

Output

```
{ "ip": "10.20.207.250,10.20.191.249,10.20.223.249" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution that uses `getent` rather than `nslookup` or `dig`.

```
$ printf "{ \"ip\": \"%s\" }\n" "$(getent hosts nlb-private-1-6ec90b26d1c9e906.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs | tr ' ' ',' )"
{ "ip": "10.20.191.249,10.20.223.249,10.20.207.250" }
$
```